# UI Bootstrap Angular Modal Not showing

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a simple view of the angular UI modal bootstrap (no javascript being used). What is the problem with my code?

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.1.js"></script>

<a id="myModal" href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default">Download csv</a>

<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Download</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Click here to download .csv file</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: just tried adding other bootstrap.js and jquery. Still not working. Confirmed on jsfiddle (without the UI angular bootstrap)

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js,
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: It not a valid angular app? This site is usually not for "Please debug my code". you will need to be more specific...

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your controller.

Comment: Have you created an angular module and included ui bootstrap inside it?

Comment: yes, I do have an angular module and have ui.bootstrap as a dep. but I dont have any js for the Modal, just the html? It won't show up when I click the button.

Comment: just because you include the angular and angular-ui scripts it doesn't make it an angular app